# Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

i am new to coding and try to update a field in a sqlite db, but i ran into an error which i dont understand.

```
sql_update_query = """Update assets set lastdatechecked = ? """
data = 'HELLO'
cursorObj.execute(sql_update_query, data,)
con.commit()
```

This is throwing an error:
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied.

But why? 'Hello' is a single string, why is it counting the letters?

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide `data` as a tuple: `(data,)`